# SQLite print out history of daily price changes of a stock

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have to output price change for each stock based on the dates that are held at the table pricedates.
What I have currently come up with is to group prices by id_stock and order by price_date in ASC order, then subtract from every row.
It should be separately done for buy_price and sell_price.

The logic should be like this

```
stock_id   prices     history
    1      price 1    price 1
           price 60   price 60-price1
           price 98   price98-price60
    2      price 34   price34
           price 67   price67-price34
```

I am really struggling with putting everything together, here is something that I have tried, most probably it's a total mess:

```
select p.id_price
(select min(pd.price_date) from pricedates pd as po where po.price_date > pd.price_date) as next_id_price,
(po.buy_price - pd.buy_price) buy
(po.sell_price - pd.sell_price) sell
from prices p
left join pricedates pd on pd.id_date=p.id_price_date
group by p.id_stock
order by pd.price_date asc;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running SQLite  >= 3.25, you can use window function `lag()` to access the previous record of the same `stock_id`:

```
select 
    p.stock_id, 
    p.buy_price,
    p.buy_price - lag(p.buy_price, 1, 0) 
        over(partition by p.stock_id order by pd.price_date) buy_history,
    p.sell_price,
    p.sell_price - lag(p.sell_price, 1, 0) 
        over(partition by p.stock_id order by pd.price_date) sell_history
from prices p
inner join pricedates pd 
    on pd.id_date = p.id_price_date
order by pd.price_date asc;
```

In earlier vesions of SQLite, where `lag()` is not available, one solution is to self-join the table with a correlated subquery that locates the *previous* record:

```
select
    p.stock_id, 
    p.buy_price,
    p.buy_price - coalesce(p1.buy_price, 0) buy_history,
    p.sell_price,
    p.sell_price - coalesce(p1.sell_price, 0) sell_history
from prices p
inner join pricedates pd 
    on pd.id_date = p.id_price_date
left join prices p1 
    on  p1.stock_id = p.stock_id
    and p1.id_date = (
        select pd1.id_date 
        from pricedates pd1
        where pd1.price_date > pd.price_date
        order by pd1.price_date 
        limit 1
    )
order by pd.price_date asc;
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! Can you please tell me, how can I access values that I got as buy_history if I also want to get the result in %?
I tried to add like this
:p.buy_price - lag(p.buy_price, 1, 0) 
        over(partition by p.stock_id order by pd.price_date) buy_history, buy_history/100,
but got an error that this column doesn't exist.

Comment: Welcome @Marietta. You need to repeat the expression if you want to use it twice.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `lag()` -- which is available in the more recent versions of SQLite:

```
select p.*,
       (price -
        lag(p.price, 1, 0) over (partition by stock_id order by id_price_date)
       ) as diff
from price p;
```